# Authentication credentials are not provided - Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, request

here is my action of redux:

```
export const addToWishlist = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        const {
            userLogin: { userInfo },
        } = getState()

        const config = {
            headers: {

                'Authorization': `JWT ${userInfo.token}`
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/wishlist/add_to_wishlist/${id}/`, config
        )


        dispatch({
            type: WISHLIST_ADD_ITEM,
            payload: data
        })




        localStorage.setItem('wishlistItems', JSON.stringify(getState().wishlist.wishlistItemsFromStorage))
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: WISHLIST_ADD_ITEM_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail
                ? error.response.data.detail
                : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

so i tried to send a post request to this api end point `/api/wishlist/add_to_wishlist/${id}/` it says in response(from redux extension)

```
type:"WISHLIST_ADD_ITEM_FAIL"
payload:"Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

`Authentication credentials we…provided.`
but when I tried the same end point using postman it worked i.e. it add the item to wishlist.

[image: postman image]

**What I tried**

- I tried to copy the token from console and paste it on postman it worked but again not on frontend
- i even tried to hard copy the same token from postman to action code and it still says the same error
- I tried change the config code and added content-type = applicaton/json but all in vain.

---

so can you please help me. Thanks .if you are curious here is view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def add_to_wishlist(request, id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, _id=id)
    if product.users_wishlist.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        product.users_wishlist.remove(request.user)
    else:
        product.users_wishlist.add(request.user)
    return Response('your item is add to the wishlist ')
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in frontend please try like this.

```
   const config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: `/api/wishlist/add_to_wishlist/${id}/`,
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        },
            data : {},
    };
    const { data } = await axios(config);
    ...
```

Comment: I don't know how but it worked . Thanks a lot